# DateTime Field is not showing dateTime picker on MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting DateTime field on MVC page but it does not show on Page
I am writing in the model,

```
[Display(Name = "Next Meeting")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? NextMeeting { get; set; }
```

And on View,

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NextMeeting, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NextMeeting, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NextMeeting, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And When I was Run my MVC web page it shows a simple textbox field,
[image: This is a text field]

How can I show DateTime field on the page?

Comment: For a start it needs to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format), but the HTML-5 datepicker is not supported an all browsers

Comment: thanks for the reply Stephen, it's correct the datepicker is not supported on Internet Explorer but I want to get. Thats why I am asking a question , what is the solution for that field to get DateTime picker?

Comment: Use a jquery plugin (for example [jQuery-ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/))

Comment: The jQuery datepicker is not working in MVC4 when I run the page, It shows an error

Comment: Then your code is wrong!